# Change ImageView Source inside CustomListView Template using MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Trying to create a app using xamarin.android

I wanted to create a list view for that purpose I have created a customTemplate like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/greenStripOnList"
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:id="@+id/taskStatus"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl StatusColor(Flag)" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I am calling the above Custom Template in my Actual ListView file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/TaskListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource RecordList"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/customtasklistview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have created a ValueConverter which returns the Image Source like Below

```
public class StatusColorValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<int, string>
    {
        protected override string Convert(int value, Type targetType, object parameter,   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string TaskStatus = string.Empty;
            switch ((int)value)
            {
                case 1:
                    TaskStatus = "@drawable/greenStripOnList";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    TaskStatus = "@drawable/yellowStripOnList";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    TaskStatus = "@drawable/redStripOnList";
                    break;
                default:
                    TaskStatus = "@drawable/greenStripOnList";
                    break;
            }
            return TaskStatus;
        }
    }
```

But I am not able to change the Image Source...

Please guide me what needs to be changed to get this working

Just wanted to change the image based on the integer value passed to the StatusColor Converter

thanks
Aman

Answer (score 1):

When you use strings like `@drawable/greenStripOnList` in axml, then the Android SDK tools preprocess the axml (before app compilation) and takes those strings and converts them into integer placeholders for the resources. Because of this you can't use the same format string at runtime.

However, the MvvmCross download cache plugin does allow you to use a Uri format `res:greenStripOnList` to achieve a similar effect - see it's implementation in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1ec7bc5f0307595c7ae11f56727dd0e9d2a2262f/Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Droid/MvxAndroidLocalFileImageLoader.cs#L25

Alternatively, there are also `DrawableName` and `DrawableId` binding pseudo-properties for ImageView's - you can see their registration in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs#L105